# Getting xlsx file from an .aspx webpage in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read an .xlsx file from the following URL, but `pd.read_excel` is giving an error even though the file can be successfully downloaded from the browser.

http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0")
```

The traceback is

```
>>> data=pd.read_excel("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
[...]
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; 
found b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00}\xceuZ'
```

Comment: [Please remove noises in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Show your code and/or error messages?

Comment: try use liburl2 and dont post link to xls (or any kind of document) contaings automatic macros, we cannot know your intentions

Comment: I edite my question

Answer (score 1):

The first four bytes shown, `\x1f\x8b\x08\x00`, make it clear that we're receiving a gzipped file, which pandas isn't automatically decompressing.  We can do it ourselves, though:

```
In [54]: import urllib.request, gzip

In [55]: df = pd.read_excel(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=urllib.request.urlopen(url)))

In [56]: df.iloc[:5, :5]
Out[56]: 
  دیده بان بازار : 1396/11/14 - زمان آخرین معامله : 14:42:03  \
0                                               نماد           
1                                                فسا           
2                                              فرآور           
3                                              فملي2           
4                                              وبملت           

                Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3    Unnamed: 4  
0                      نام      تعداد        حجم          ارزش  
1             پتروشيمي فسا        512    5251556    3647287532  
2  فرآوري‌موادمعدني‌ايران‌        310     694381   11249763313  
3   ملي‌ صنايع‌ مس‌ ايران‌          1   40949671  115887568930  
4                 بانك ملت        350    6350364    6561761997
```

The remaining tweaks to get the columns set appropriately aren't related to the problem in the post and so I'll leave those alone.